# How to insert Integer value in DB - PHP

Tags: php

I have using PHP for inserting integer value in Database.

Iam using like this

```
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$mysql_user_resultset = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into user (postcode) VALUES ($postcode)");
```

I have several field in DB. like name, username, etc. all are defined as varchar, but postcode only defined as int. If not enter the value for postcode, it doesn't insert into database

Comment: Can you add a var_dump($postcode) before the insert?

Comment: From your example: `$postcode = isset($_POST['postcode'])?$_POST['postcode']:0;`, so if the postcode is not set, it will be set to 0. Also, you **should escape your passed parameters**.

Comment: You can use [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) or [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) to make your your postcode is an integer.

Comment: @Prasanth `is_numeric` will *not* ensure something is an integer; it supports all sorts of formats, like `'0.1e-05'`. To check for digits only, you need [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit)

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not check for the data to be inputted first, and **then** insert it?

Comment: "`If not enter the value for postcode, it doesn't insert into database`" - how could it? What would it enter of there is not value? What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply cast your variable into int:

```
$postcode = (int) $_POST['postcode'];
$mysql_user_resultset = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into user (postcode) VALUES ($postcode)");
```

Note that you're not using any precautions regarding SQL injections, I would suggest you to bind your parameters before query them, [using PDO class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Answer (score 1):

Convert `$_POST['postcode']` to `int`, using

```
$postcode = (int)$_POST['postcode'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO or sprintf for formatting mysql query:

[sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php) example:

```
$mysql_user_resultset = mysqli_query($con, sprintf(
  "INSERT into user (postcode) VALUES (%d)", 
$_POST['postcode']));
```

PDO [example](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php):

```
$st = $db->prepare("INSERT into vendors user (postcode) VALUES (:postcode)");
$st->bindParam(':postcode', $_POST['postcode'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$mysql_user_resultset = $st->execute();
```